# Reformatting a txt file with characters at certain positions using python

Tags: python, txt, reformatting

Very newbie programmer asking a question here. I have searched all over the forums but can't find something to solve this issue I thought there would be a simple function for. Is there a way to do this?

I am trying to reformat a txt file so I can use it with the pandas function but this requires my data to be in a specific format.

Currently my data is in the following format of a txt file:

```
01/09/21,00:28,7.1,75,3.0,3.7,3.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.8,81.9,17.1,44,3.7,4.6,7.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,00:58,7.0,75,2.9,5.1,5.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.9,81.9,17.0,44,5.1,3.8,7.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.9,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0
```

it is required to be formatted like this for processing using pandas:

```
["06/09/21","19:58",11.4,69,5.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.3,1006.6,82.2,21.8,52,0.0,11.4,11.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,10.5,0,1.5,0,0.0,0.3],
["06/09/21","20:28",10.6,73,6.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.3,1006.3,82.2,22.4,49,0.0,10.6,10.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,9.7,0,1.5,0,0.0,0.3],
```

This requires adding a `["` at the start and adding a `"` at the end of the date before the comma, then adding another `"` after the comma and another `"` at the end of the time section. At the end of the line, I also need to add a `],`

I thought something like this would work but i get an error when trying to run it.

```
info = 
    06/09/21,19:58,11.4,69,5.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.3,1006.6,82.2,21.8,52,0.0,11.4,11.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,10.5,0,1.5,0,0.0,0.3
    
    
info=info[:1] +"['" +info[1:]


print (info)
```

I have over 1000 lines of data so doing it manually is out of the question. I've seen other questions like this, but they didn't get helpful answers. Can it be done, preferably with either a method or a loop?

Comment: That line `info=` is missing surrounding quotes.  That's why Python is raising an error.  That is, `info='06/09/21...'

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the CONTENTS of your data with the REPRESENTATION of your data.  You don't really need brackets and quotes at all.  What you need is a list that contains strings and integers.  What you've shown there is how Python would PRINT a list containing strings and integers.  The list doesn't actually contain brackets or quotes.

You can use `pandas.read_csv` directly on that data file with no extra processing.  You just need to provide the column names.